# Jquery .slideToggle navigation menu. All menus slide and I only want one to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, slidetoggle

I am trying to make a `dropdown` navigation and right now I am trying to get just one `menu` to `dropdown` but they all do. Here is all my code: 
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ramabhadra' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Khand:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <ul class="cats">
        <li class="listItems" id="home">Home</li>
        <li class="listItems" id="dashboard">Dashboard</li>
        <li class="listItems" id="contactUs">Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class='dropdownHome'>
    <ul class="catLists">
        <li class="catListItem">Event Calender</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Bookings</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Picture Gallery</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Login</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Sign Up</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdownDashboard">
    <ul class="catLists">
        <li class="catListItem">Saved Info</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Friends</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Document</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Profile</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Account</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdownContactUs">
    <ul class="catLists">
        <li class="catListItem">Email</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Forum</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Phone-numbers</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Facebook</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Twitter</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
    background-color:black;
    height:50px;
    border-radius:10px;
    z-index:1;
}
li {
    color:white;
    display:inline;
    width:100%
}
.cats {
    padding:6px;
    width:100%;
    font-size:29px;
    font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
}
.cats .listItems:hover {
    width:100px;
    font-size:29px;
    font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
    color:#96F29C;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    padding-left:70px;
}
.cats .listItems:active {
    width:100px;
    font-size:29px;
    font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
    color:#318A29;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    padding-left:70px;
}
.listItems {
    padding:70px;
}
.dropdownHome {
    height:200px;
    width:180px;
    background-color:#9E9E9E;
    position:relative;
    left:18px;
    bottom:10px;
    border:2px solid black;
    z-index:-1;
    border-radius:13px;
}
.dropdownDashboard {
    height:200px;
    width:180px;
    background-color:#9E9E9E;
    position:relative;
    right:290px;
    bottom:214px;
    border:2px solid black;
    z-index:-1;
    float:right;
    border-radius:13px;
}
.dropdownContactUs {
    height:200px;
    width:180px;
    background-color:#9E9E9E;
    position:relative;
    left:140px;
    bottom:214px;
    border:2px solid black;
    z-index:-1;
    float:right;
    border-radius:13px;
}
.catLists {
    font-size:18px;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    right:20;
    font-family: 'Ramabhadra', sans-serif;
}
.catListItem {
    color:black;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#home').click(function(){
        $('.dropdownHome').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

My question was originally something different but now that I fixed my other problem I need to know how to fix this. Another thing that I assume will get fixed with my original problem is that when the other two `dropdown` `menus` slide up (the ones that are not supposed to) they go above the header div. It is hard to explain but you will notice what I mean if you put it in a text editor and run it then click the home option. If this is something I have to fix separately please tell me how. Thank you.

Comment: Works fine when I test it. Can you show more code - have you included the library?

Comment: check error in your browser console

Comment: Somehow the library un-linked in my html thank you for pointing that out. It works now but my only problem is that all of my drop down menus scroll up not just the home one. I edited my question and put my full code in it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a way to position **.dropdownContactUs** and **.dropdownDashboard** without using floats, they'll stop moving up and down with the **dropdownHome**. The reason they're scrolling up now is because with them being floated and them being relatively position to their container (**body**), the container only goes down far enough to contain **.dropdownHome** which means when it moves up, they have to move up too. Remember, when using floats, it takes the elements out of the flow of the document which means they don't effect the size of any elements on the page. In turn, they can be effected by where everything else is positioned.

Comment: Thank you. It worked, but now whenever I click dashboard or contact us they scroll from top to bottom but I want the to scroll from bottom to top. If you have any advice that would be great. Thank you.